# Is it possible to check that a key of an object is key of a generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function that returns an object whose index is a key of an existing type.

```js
type ResponseGeneric<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: {
    otherProp: any
  };
}

function validateGeneric<T>(key: keyof T, value: any): ResponseGeneric<T> {
  return {
    [key]: {
      otherProp: value,
    },
  };
}
```

But with this I have the following error in `validateGeneric`:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: { otherProp: any; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ResponseGeneric<T>'.ts(2322)
```

I'm aware that I could workaround this with a casting at the return, but I was wondering if there could be a way with the latest TypeScript version (currently 4.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrapped this up right after I saw jcaiz's post. I like his answer, too, but since I'd already gotten this far, I figured I'd post for posterity. On the bright side, I didn't end up using the cast approach, so maybe this is a different take.

**JS code:**

```
type ResponseGeneric<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: {
    otherProp: any
  };
}

function validateGeneric<T>(key: keyof T, value: any): ResponseGeneric<T> {
  let response: ResponseGeneric<T> = {};

  response[key] = {
    otherProp: value,
  };

  return response;
}

// Example type
type TypeTee = {
  bob: string
}
let teeObject: TypeTee = {
  bob: "Alice"
}

const response: ResponseGeneric<TypeTee> = validateGeneric("bob", "Eve");
console.log("JSON: " + JSON.stringify(response));
```

**Code outputs:**

```
JSON: {"bob":{"otherProp":"Eve"}}
```

**JS Playground**

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7eEDiEUQE4EsBjAHgBUA%20KAXigG8BYAKCigG0BpKfFKAawhBIAZlFIBdAPwAuOkxYskwABZ4ACriRgZAQxQg5UAL4BuJoaZMhAVxSFg%20VFABu2gDb4AJtuCZseImTkABT8IDKhwqIANM5uVhA6egCUMnCIqOhYOAQkFLLMUK4QwFC4CMhoCbDlGb7ZAXk0tCYWBWXplayhYtT58lCKKrjqmjIurvFRBi2MBmXAVrg87RXopozms4wA9NtQAKIAHtoAtmBFUKCQTFfQpOAQpBDQTQYARkhvMvDABCgA5mYmEUSj4IAB5N4AKwgdhk90gTxefSgHy%20UAARABBdyECAYoFbQgZEorWqpGqVLL%20XIPJGUGjjTzeOo0oIYtEYmIY-ZOfFJdbEtBIIoAOlcSH%207IAUgBlcEAORkGKgAGooHLFaKfn9-vghCAgmTKkkBUwgA)

Comment: Why did you set `K` as property name in `ResponseGeneric`? This way it only suggest me property `K` when typing `response.`. The script output is the same for me, though.

Comment: That critique makes sense. I'll take another look when I'm in front of a keyboard.

Comment: @AgustinGarcia - Ok. I was able to modify this, and now that I look at it.. I ended up with your original code. Hah.. Output remains the same as before. I did have to change the object populate and return-style in the validate method though to get rid of the error message you had posted in the original post.. So maybe it this was what you really wanted to do all along...

Comment: Updated to add link to playground.

Answer (score 4):

This is still either a bug or a design limitation of TypeScript, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) [microsoft/TypeScript#21030](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030).  If you have a computed property name of a generic type (like `keyof T`), the compiler widens this all the way to `string` and makes the resulting object have a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

Apparently there was work done to address this, in [microsoft/TypeScript#21070](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21070), but it had more of an impact than the team wanted to accept, so it was never merged. And it doesn't look like it's been revisited.

Until and unless anything changes, you will need to work around it.  The easiest way is, as you mentioned, to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (this is the preferred term; the word "cast" sometimes implies runtime behavior changes, while TypeScript type assertions have no runtime effects at all):

```
function validateGeneric<K extends PropertyKey>(key: K, value: any) {
  return {
    [key]: {
      otherProp: value,
    },
  } as { [P in K]?: { otherProp: any } };
}
```

Note that instead of using the type parameter `T` from some object type, I have changed it to use just a key type `K`.  Your definition of `ResponseGeneric` completely threw away any information it had from the property values from `T` and only kept the keys, so we might as well not try to infer an object type when there is none.

```
const result = validateGeneric("a", 123);
/* const result: {
    a?: {
        otherProp: any;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

---

If you find that you are doing this sort of thing a lot, you can confine the type assertion to a single helper function like this:

```
const kv = <K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, val: V) => ({
  [key]: val
}) as K extends any ? { [P in K]: V } : never;
```

and then use the helper function in places where you would otherwise be writing a computed property:

```
function validateGeneric2<K extends PropertyKey>(key: K, value: any) {
  return kv(key, { otherProp: value })
}

validateGeneric2("a", 123).a.otherProp // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBNVQKYDieYeATjBADwDSieAHvmFgM6IAKpcADmVAJ7U8-AHwAKANbCAXImoAaFBhB5ZqMPwCUiAN4BYAFCJEpPFBCkk+o8cQBtKfwC6s67dtwoACzKcestHQVeUN3AF8QmzDEVDYde3ZEGCRqJwB+V0RPH1I-bjUNRGiwgG5DMMNDCAQWKBM8FhB0OoBeJUwcfCIScggxACJUfsUARgAmAGZNMoMAegAqRGqwWvrG5tdQ21QM3S33Y2zfLnyYjRnwxAAfRHAsPGBkvCwZ6PnZyoNP5dWJZEQ2jQ6IxiKwOCc+IJhIoAGriRyyBTtWQw7QtESIMRueyOFztcraWJyYFMMHqfiINK6BJJFJ4mFFRCyEjIMgzT6gSCwBDtbC4QjEMgUMZAhikth5SFCUSSGRyRSBFQFLR7GymcyWRB-WX8RTxI65E4BZR4IqacqfQJ8rqC3pjAZDUaTTQAOlQLoNeUQs1mWQkqH4QA)