# How do I declare the return types based on function arguments in typescript

Tags: typescript

I use the below function to group items based on a property. E.g I would like to group the cars array by year.

So I pass the year as key, cars array as items and cars as itemsName.

And the function returns an array of objects like

```
[
{
year: 2012,
cars: [{make: ‘Audi’, model: ‘r8’}, {make: ‘Ford’, model: ‘mustang’}]
}
]
```

My question is how do I declare types or interfaces for the returned values? Please note that I will use different arrays e.g a restaurants array to group them by scheduled date so the types needs to dynamic.

```
const cars = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    },
];

// Group items by property
export function groupBy(key, items, itemsName) {
  // Crate groups with provided key
  const groupsObj = items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    // Property to create group with
    const property = curr[key];

    // If property exists in acc then,
    // add the current item to the property array
    if (property in acc) {
      return { ...acc, [property]: [...acc[property], curr] };
    }

    // Else create a property and
    // add the current item to an array
    return { ...acc, [property]: [curr] };
  }, {});

  // Convert the object
  const groupsArr = Object.keys(groupsObj).map((property) => ({
    [key]: property,
    [itemsName]: groupsObj[property],
  }));

  return groupsArr;
}
```

Comment: "when I call the function typescript says..." could you show this with a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about when you paste the code into a standalone IDE?  Right now you've given a function but the error occurs in code you're not showing.  It's easier to get to work on a problem if I have the problem in front of me; otherwise I have to work on *re-creating* the problem, which lowers the chance of success.

Comment: I meant how do I call this function with different key (string), items (array), and itemsName (string) and return the correct interface key?

Comment: Great, could you [edit] the question and show what you're talking about in code, so that you have a [mre]?  Otherwise in order to answer this, I need to convert your English text into code before I even get to start on the issue.

Comment: I don't see you calling `groupBy()` here or trying to use the results.  Presumably `cars` is one of the inputs, but it has other inputs and then you have some problem with the output.  If I have to do extra work to reproduce the problem you're talking about, then there's a chance I'm doing it wrong.  I'm not sure how else to explain what a [mre] is.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m36P2N) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This seems interesting! Please write your answer. Sorry for not being able to explain it correctly. I am not on a computer at the moment.

Comment: By the way, I can't get my head around what you meant by Q here: 

type Grouped<T extends object, K extends keyof T, P extends PropertyKey> = { [Q in K]: T[K] } & { [Q in P]: T[] };

Comment: It's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html); the `Q` is a type parameter that iterates over union members of `K`; of course we expect `K` to be a single type, then `Q` will only end up being equal to `K`.  `{[Q in K]: V}` is equivalent to `Record<K, V>`, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to give `groupBy()` the call signature

```
function groupBy<T extends Record<K, string>, K extends keyof T, P extends PropertyKey>(
  key: K, items: T[], itemsName: P): Grouped<T, K, P>[] { /*...*/ }
```

where `Grouped` is defined as

```
type Grouped<T extends object, K extends keyof T, P extends PropertyKey> =
  { [Q in K]: T[K] } & { [Q in P]: T[] };
```

In order for the return type of `groupBy()` to depend on its argument types, you pretty much need it to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in every type you need to keep track of.  Here I've made it generic in three type parameters.  There's `T`, the element type of the `items` array; there's `K`, the type of the `key` argument, and `P`, the type of the `itemsName` argument.

It's important to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) these type parameters to just valid inputs.  For example, we want to make sure that `K` is one of the keys of `T`; hence `K extends keyof T` using [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html).  We also want to make sure that `T` has a `string` value at the `K` property, so you can use it as an index of `groupsObj` inside your implementation (I kind of think `groupsObj` is a more useful output than an array you have to search through, but that's up to you); hence `T extends Record<K, string>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).  And finally we want to make sure that `P` is some keylike type; hence `P extends PropertyKey` using [the `PropertyKey` type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4f54e7e947298162d29f3104265e74dcfbc90d82/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L107).

So that takes care of the input... how about the output?  The type `Grouped<T, K, P>` is intended to be the element type of the returned array.  It is equivalent to `Record<K, T[K]> & Record<P, T[]>`.  That means it has a property with key `K` (the same as `key`) whose value is of the same type `T` has at key `K` (represented by the [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) type `T[K]`), *and* (represented by the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `&`) it has a property with key `P` (the same as `itemsName`) whose value is an array of `T` (the same type as `items`).

---

Let's make sure we can use it:

```
interface Car {
  make: string;
  model: string;
  year: string;
}
const cars: Car[] = [/*...*/]

const ret = groupBy("year", cars, "cars");
/* const ret: Grouped<Car, "year", "cars">[] */

const str = ret.map(
  v => v.year + ": " + v.cars.map(
//^      ^^^^-- (property) year: string    
//|--- (parameter) v: Grouped<Car, "year", "cars">
    c => c.make + " " + c.model
//  ^ <-- (parameter) c: Car
  ).join(", ")
).join("\n");
```

So `ret` is of type `Grouped<Car, "year", "cars">[]`, which means it's an array of objects with a `year` property of type `string`, and a `cars` property of type `Car[]`.  So it works well from the caller's side.

---

As for the implementation, you need to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) and [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) types in some places to remind/persuade/force the compiler to see that it conforms to that call signature.  Here's one way to do it:

```
function groupBy<T extends Record<K, string>, K extends keyof T, P extends PropertyKey>(
  key: K, items: T[], itemsName: P): Grouped<T, K, P>[] {

  const groupsObj = items.reduce<Record<string, T[]>>((acc, curr) => {
    const property: string | number = curr[key];
    if (property in acc) {
      return { ...acc, [property]: [...acc[property], curr] };
    }
    return { ...acc, [property]: [curr] };
  }, {});

  const groupsArr = Object.keys(groupsObj).map((property) => ({
    [key]: property,
    [itemsName]: groupsObj[property],
  }) as Grouped<T, K, P>);

  return groupsArr;
}
```

We have to tell the compiler that the initial object `{}` passed to the [`reduce()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is of type `Record<string, T[]>` so that it understands that you'll be placing arrays of `T` in its property values no matter what the key is.

And we need to just assert that `{[key]: property, [itemsName]: groupsObj[property]}` is of type `Grouped<T, K, P>` since it doesn't understand how to give strong typings to computed properties whose keys are generic (see [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526162/2887218) for details).

---

So now that all compiles and hopefully works as you need.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-72YIlchJwvl8Z22BZ8qsMgW0AycEnUR82X+VV1EAltJ1Ajdn3jRRZygbRJCYLJpCyb9fwVaDgP0MDN0gi8UI1I4sEkTNfhXOQFGrcFKAAQTnRt62xXEW3JShg3ou46yxTMWyIO5gwfeD-gXHReWDT8ry5VVCOfFZjHURNmxTNMIFVXj+MxOCnwg5TKLfVFc3BDsC1FIsqJwZhsKgfVDT45ioCkWzV0rb9G14k1gwAInKPzp2UBI-KUAo-JsgB6AAqRRaM8iAwBzJyLLUULAtC8LKD84ttBiqL3ISqgaEbb8hLgETmAAN0XZBqpbcpkAAamQPyKD8lr6pbbKKqqrIoqigA9LJ8CG8ahoAWkm5AxIMwQF3Kbd6CyAJBr3aaZofDBNMged6pSvM0owDKxiCtrstygIEDqhAKtILrOs61q7uuNaorG5BIWm2a7h29M9oXBBVAwZhBMxFhQH80LMxwcHIZAfyAB0QEi35VxYTgIBbTgWDoYNeBsnBYrayYKHSYBkF8BI2g6QgBjAIY6ASc44DRB4njgHAqmqcm7EpgpCm5g4KFpthkC1Sg9U6gqgA)